# nginx reverse caching proxy doesnt cache static files

Tags: nginx

I have configured `nginx` as reverse caching proxy in front of `apache`
but it does not cache static contents & caching directory is always empty
the following is contents of virtualhost

```
server {
    root   /home/xxxx/public_html;
    server_name xxxxx.com.xx www.xxxx.com.xx;
    error_log  /usr/local/nginx/logs/vhost-error_log warn;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
    location ~* \.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|css|js|xml|swf|pdf|flv|htm|html)$ {
    proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires" "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    root   /home/xxxx/public_html;
    proxy_cache nginx-cache;
    proxy_cache_valid any 30m;
    expires modified +90d;
    }
    
    location / {
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass   http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
    }

}
```

The following is the contents of `proxy.conf` file :

```
    proxy_buffering On;
    proxy_buffers  3000 6m;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size  12m;
    proxy_buffer_size 6m;
    output_buffers 500 6m;
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri";
    proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
    proxy_pass_header "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size 50m;
    client_body_buffer_size 4m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_send_timeout 300s;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache $arg_comment;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
```

The following are contents of `nginx.conf`

```
    user  nobody;
    worker_processes 4;
    worker_rlimit_nofile 4000;
    thread_pool default threads=128 max_queue=65536;
    pid        /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
    events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  4000;
    multi_accept On;
    accept_mutex off;
    }
    http {
    aio threads=default;
    access_log /dev/null;
    error_log /dev/null;
    server_tokens Off;
    log_format  main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
                      '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp;
    proxy_cache_path /home/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx-cache:1m max_size=4g inactive=6h use_temp_path=off;
    open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=6h;
    open_file_cache_valid 6h;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors Off;
    proxy_temp_path /home/nginx_cache/tmp;
    server_names_hash_max_size 512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 512;
    server_name_in_redirect On;
    port_in_redirect Off;
    tcp_nodelay On;
    tcp_nopush On;
    sendfile On;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    reset_timedout_connection On;
    if_modified_since before;
    gzip On;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_disable msie6;
    gzip_min_length 10;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript application/atom+xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/xml image/x-icon text/x-js application/xhtml+xml image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    server {
    server_name xx.xx.com;
    root /usr/local/nginx/html;
    listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80 ;
    location / {
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass   http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
    }
    }
    include       /usr/local/nginx/conf/vhost.conf;
    }
```

Please could anyone here helps me to find out why cache directory doesnt caching static contents as shown :

```
    tmpfs           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /home/nginx_cache
```

Comment: Have you looked at the output of curl for a static resource? What does it say?

Comment: Hello keenan thank you man for your respond, actually i didnt & also dont know how to use curl for checking static, so could you help me on this ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your initial question. So the reason as to why your cache is empty is because that's a proxy cache, and you're not proxying any requests in the static location block (so nothing ever gets cached). This, however, is not a bad thing. Nginx is really good at serving static files, and these files will be cached by the browser if they're given the correct headers namely: `add_header Pragma public;` `add_header Cache-Control "public";` Any directive with a `proxy` prefix can be removed from this location block. Once you've done this, restart Nginx

Comment: To confirm if it is indeed being cached, you can use [Google's Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to analyse your page.

Comment: thank you Keenan, what you have mentioned will cache static files in users browser but i need to cache static files in both users browsers & file system to aviod asking apache for static contents in order to speedup page load time, so can you help me on this ? many thanks again

Comment: Ah, I see... So as a test, you can do the following. In your location block where you've specified your static file extensions, add this line `add_header Serving "Nginx";` Restart Nginx and then do a curl for a static file. From the command-line, `curl -I http://www.xxxx.com.xx/uri/to/static/file.png` If you see a header `Serving Nginx` then requests for static files aren't going to Apache, but being delivered by Nginx.

Comment: hello keenan, i have add your recommended two add_header lines without any improvements in google pagespeed, also i have checked css file using curl & get the following : 
<code> 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2016 12:38:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 279
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.xxxx.com.xxx/catalog/view/theme/journal2/css/icons/style.css
Vary: Accept-Encoding
</code>

Comment: Are you sure you've posted your entire Nginx config? You're getting a 301 redirect but there are no redirects specified in your config.

Comment: Hello Keenan yeah man i have added all three nginx files, also i have tested your curl command after adding nginx header but nothing changed as shown : 
`code` HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2016 12:48:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.xxx.com.xxx/image/img1.png
Vary: Accept-Encoding
 `code`

Comment: why i get moved permanently ??

Comment: Keenan it gives me moved permanently because i have missed www in the URL, so i added www then tried again & it gives me the following : 
curl -I http://www.xxx.com.xx/image/img1.png
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2016 12:54:29 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 66071
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Sun, 31 Jan 2016 11:36:38 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes

Comment: I've replicated your setup and I'm receiving the additional header. Can you post any updates that you've made?

Comment: Hello Keenan, i have no updates to nginx configuration files, except for virtualhost i added add_header Serving "Nginx"; & add_header Pragma public; add_header Cache-Control "public"; but nothing changes